# Updating the state via eventHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The piece of code below is a two-way binding in **ReactJS**, whereas one types, the text and input values update simultaneously.

Here's the Component loop:

```
if (this.state.personState){

  persons = (

    <div> 

      {this.state.person.map( (person, index) =>{
          return 
             <Person 
                click = {()=>this.deletePerson(index)}
                name = {person.name} 
                age = {person.age} 
                key = {person.id} 
                changed = { (event)=>this.changeNameHandler(event, person.id)} >
             </Person>
      })}

    </div>

)
```

The function that handles the event

```
changeNameHandler = (event, id) => {

   const personIndex = this.state.person.findIndex(person => person === id)

   // making a copy and not manipulating the original reference
   const personcpy = { ...this.state.person[personIndex] }

   // assign the value of the event target
   personcpy.name = event.target.value;

   // making a copy of the state to update the dom
   const persons = [...this.state.person]

   // updating...
   persons[personIndex] = personcpy

   // state update
   this.setState({ persons : persons })

}
```

The Javascript Object itself

```
state = {
  person : [
    {id:'12121', name:"Jimmy", age:12},
    {id:'121s', name:"Jack", age:15},
    {id:'23232a', name:"pouya", age:27}
  ]
}
```

The component codes

```
const Person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="Person" >
        <p  onClick={props.click}>I'm {props.name} and I'm {props.age} years old</p>
        <input  onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
        <h1 >{props.name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm aware that **findIndex()** returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the given test.

And I'm testing if the index of the event on change is the same as the object one!

However, this does not work, and when I try to type it just freezes

I've checked Chrom's developer tools and tried to debug there, it seems like there is a reference error! but I don't understand! how could that be?

[image]

Please help me see from different point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get an valid personIndex? Probably you should write findIndex(person => person.id === id)

Comment: Jeezoz! actually the findIndex returns the elements, and those are the sub-property of my object! and I needed the id of them, and not them, themselves! thanks a lot mate...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that reference of `this.state.person` not changed, component will not re-render.
try this below in changeNameHandler:

```
// ...ellipsis code ...

this.setState({ person: [...persons] })
```

And in your state, `person` is declared, but update `persons` in `setState`, is that miss type?